# How to run JavaScript in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I'm new at this so apologies in advance if I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not able to figure out how to run JavaScript in WebStorm. The [WebStorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/running-and-debugging-javascript.html) says to simply open the HTML file in the browser, but that doesn't seem to work. For what it's worth, everything is working up on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/ahlstromvij/pen/qRyryX).

Here's the HTML (for a simple weather app):

```html
<body>
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="white-box text-center">
            <span>Weather where you are:</span>
            <div class="loc"></div>
            <div class="weather"></div>
            <div class="temp"></div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And here's the script (still in draft, as it needs to be expanded to, among other things, link to images covering all values for 'weather'):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( window ).on("load", function(){
        $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(json) {
            var json;
            json = JSON.stringify(json);
            var obj = JSON.parse(json);
            var latitude = obj.lat;
            var longitude = obj.lon;

            $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude+"&appid=74a6725c2ca6f1342464bb9005bf0b63", function(json) {
                var json;
                json = JSON.stringify(json);
                var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                var loc = obj.name;
                var weather = obj.weather[0].description;

                var tempInCelsius = obj.main.temp - 273.15;
                var tempInCelsiusString = tempInCelsius.toFixed(1) + " &#8451";

                var tempInFahrenheit = obj.main.temp * 9/5 - 459.67;
                var tempInFahrenheitString = tempInFahrenheit.toFixed(1) + " &#8457";

                var tempStringCombined = tempInCelsiusString + " | " + tempInFahrenheitString;

                $(".loc").html(loc);
                if(weather === "haze"){
                    weather = "<img src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/chubby-weather/440/fog-512.png'>";
                }
                $(".weather").html(weather);
                $(".temp").html(tempStringCombined);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: A <html> tag around the html?

Comment: Always look for errors in browser console. Note you need to run internal server if you use ajax as security restrictions prevent it in `file/open`

Comment: *"For what it's worth, everything is working up on codepen.io."* ode pen automatically will add your `.js` file (as well as jQuery library) into the HTML file .. while in your HTML you have no references to those files. WebStorm just tells your browser to open that URL. browser will not magically start looking at what JS code you are trying to run and load it from somewhere -- you have to have `<script ...>` tags in your HTML for that. here is a basic example: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide

Comment: Thanks so much, LazyOne, that worked! Added the ajax script link, and also pasted the code from the js file into the HTML doc. Just one question: how come the "<script src="script.js"></script>" didn't do the trick, since pointing to the js file containing the JS code?

Comment: "<script src="script.js"></script>" should do the trick if the script.js can be found by specified path (i.e. in your case it should be located in the same folder as .html). Also, you html is broken - `<head>` element inside `<body>`,no  `<html>`. And JQuery is not linked, so you will get referenceerror when trying to run your js. You need adding `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

Comment: and one more note: You need to open a folder where your files are located in webStorm to get a project created. If you just open a single html file via File | Open, built-in webserver won't serve it, you will get 404 error when loading your page in browser

Answer (score 1):

Select the tab of html file(say `index.html`), and click in the menu `Run > Run...` and select `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks for this, Sangbok. Locating the run command wasn't the issue. As LazyOne and lena pointed out, what was missing was a link to JQuery (e.g., <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>). That fixed the problem.